# What does "stat 1. c.18" mean?

Tags: vocabulary, archaicisms, old-english

I'm reading Adam Smith's The Wealth of Nations and I keep seeing these chronologic references to reigns of kings and queens in England:

> By the 12th of Queen Anne, too, stat. 1, c. 18

What do "by the 12th", "stat. 1" and "c. 18" mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a legal reference. It means something like "By the twelfth year of the reign of Queen Anne, too, the first statute of the session of Parliament for that year, chapter 18."

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regnal_years_of_English_monarchs

Since Anne reigned from 1702-1714, her twelfth year was her final year.

Comment: Or her 13th year?

Comment: 7 March to 1 August 1714 was all that she had of her thirteenth year.